# Relationship in Spring-jpa Infinite recursion

Tags: jackson

I have two tables Department and Employees. Department is parent of Employee and both are joined by department_id.

**Department**

```
@Entity
public class Department {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Department [departmentId=" + departmentId + ", departmentName=" + departmentName + "]";
    }

    @Id
    public Integer departmentId;

    public String departmentName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public Set<Employee> employees;

}
```

**Employee**

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [employee_id=" + employeeId + ", employee_name=" + employeeName + ", department="
                + department + "]";
    }
    @Id
    public Integer employeeId;

    public String employeeName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "departmentId")
    public Department department;

}
```

When I am trying to retrieve all department details it is creating a cyclic dependency and jackson is throwing the following error . **So I would like to know how is this case handled where you need flexibility to access the child details from parent and access parent details from child.**

```
2017-08-01 12:03:13.245  WARN 18197 --- [o-auto-1-exec-3] 
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to write HTTP message: 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not 
write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with hibernate/spring-jpa.  It is the behavior you will encounter if your object passed to jackson contains cyclic references

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this solution using the following approach @JsonIgnoreProperties. By using this way i was able to fetch employee details in department and department level details in employees and avoiding infinite recursion

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("department")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
public Set<Employee> employees;

@JsonIgnoreProperties("employees")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "departmentId")
public Department department;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` :

```
@JsonBackReference
public Department department;
```

and in Department Model

```
@JsonManagedReference
public Set<Employee> employees
```

It should work now :)

Comment: But in this case , department details will never be part of the json right?

Comment: It will be.. but the nested (employee details in the Department) will not be

Answer (score -1):

Yes this is expected, Jackson will iterate over your references and since the relation is bidirectional it will get stuck in an infinite operation.

To solve this you can use `@JsonIgnore` to ignore serializing one side of the relation to break the loop

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [employee_id=" + employeeId + ", employee_name=" + employeeName + ", department="
            + department + "]";
    }

    @Id
    public Integer employeeId;

    public String employeeName;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "departmentId")
    public Department department;

}
```

Comment: But the intent is to have the flexibility to fetch employees when departments is loaded and department details when employee is loaded

Comment: you cannot have this flexibility in the returned JSON since this is serialized data and not model